# User authentication failed in Firebase due to different package name ? Android, Java

Tags: java, android, firebase, authentication

Hope you're having a good day. Well, the app I published unable to autheticate users.
In the fingerprint sections, I include: App signing cert, release & debug signing key (all are SHA-1), but still fail.

I'm suspecting it's related to the package name. As I changed the package name of my app before publishing it. So the package name of the app(in the code and in Play store) is different form the one in Firebase.

Shall I make new project in Firebase and configure it back. Or there might be other factor?

Things I planned to do: Add a new app(in the same project), copy all the necessary SHA-1 key, delete the old one. Replace the new json file in the directory, reupload.

Or

Should I just add app without deleting the old "app"?

Which will be better ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new app, without deleting the old app, just in case you decide to change the package name again. If you are certain on this package name, you can delete the old app after adding the new app.

Comment: Okay will do. Thank you sir.